# Using javascript to validate string entered in textbox

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am working on a search box to search users of my webapp. 
I want the user to enter the firstname and lastname of the user. 
I want to validate the user and make sure that user enters two string parts viz. firstname  and lastname in the textbox.
If not done so ...i want an error to be thrown. Please help with examples.
I m new to javascript .
My webapp is jsp/servlet based.

Comment: did you try something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this example in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/YrFfG/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(e) {
    if (/\w+\s+\w+/.test($("#cname").val())) {
        alert("good");
    } else {
        alert("bad");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```